# PHP FPM Still Requires "Other" Permission on Folder

Tags: nginx, security, php-fpm, file-permissions

With NGINX and PHP-FPM, I'm having trouble configuring it for my web directory with the proper security. I have a user and group called `example.com` and they are chowned on `/home/example.com/*`. I want to run the PHP-FPM context under that. I then ran `chown -R o-rwx /home/example.com/www` to remove `rwx` permissions from anyone besides user and group. Well, when I load the web site, I get a 403 permissions error. So, I take the "other" (`o`) attribute and turn on `r` and `x` on the folder. I then do `chmod o+r index.php`. Now the 403 error goes away and I can load the page, but that's an improper configuration because I should be able to remove the "other" permission I thought?

In our FPM pool conf file, we set things like:

```
[example.com]
user: example.com
group: example.com

listen = /var/run/php-fpm-example.com.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

What are we doing wrong such that we have to enable the "other" permission on the web folder in order for the website to load with PHP-FPM?

Comment: The user `www-data` is not the user `example.com`, nor is the group...

Comment: Have you checked that the PHP-FPM workers are really running under `example.com` user?